# Fire an event in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am currently coding my first GUI application in netbeans.I have a `JComboBox` and a `JTable` in my `JFrame`.

When an Item is selected in the `ComboBox` , I want to add rows to the `JTable` but in what event shall i put the code that will fill the Jtable

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the listener to the comboBox and then get the model of the jtable and add the row

## Example:

```
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Selected: " + comboBox.getSelectedItem());
        System.out.println(", Position: " + comboBox.getSelectedIndex());

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

        model.addRow(row);
        
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either ***ActionPerformed*** event or **ItemStateChanged** event of JCOMBOBOX.

[You can right click on the JCOMBOBOX and do the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh5Ck.png)

```
   public void populateTable(JTable jt, String value) {
        DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jt.getModel();
        int rowCount = jt.getRowCount();
        for (int i = rowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            dtm.removeRow(i);
        }
        Object data[] = new Object[1];
        data[0] = value;
        dtm.addRow(data);

    }
    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String selValue =(String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        populateTable(jTable1, selValue);
    }
```

Following is the Output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWGwm.png)